# How can I configure Supervisor and scheduling with Laravel Sail?

Tags: laravel, cron, supervisord, laravel-sail

I'm using Laravel sail. I want to use supervisor and cronjob. But I don't understand how I can configure these things with sail.

I can't find any examples on how to do this.

Comment: Did you find the answer? can you share it if you have?

Comment: I found a solution for only queues that is below and it works with queues, not cronjobs. After adding these codes your supervisor.conf file you must restart containers with `docker-compose up ---build ` https://stackoverflow.com/a/68764903/15564040  @KhacNha

Answer (score 2):

Because sail uses a [Ubuntu container](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.0/Dockerfile#L1) you can follow these instructions: https://serverspace.io/support/help/automate-tasks-with-cron-ubuntu-20-04/

Typically they are stored in [`/var/spool/cron/crontabs`](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-list-display-view-all-cron-jobs-linux) so you might want to create a volume to persist them (otherwise they will be removed on the next restart of your container).

You can connect to your container with `docker-compose exec laravel.test bash` [I believe](https://gist.github.com/thomasmoors/5ab0a294637ab9fa8c96af7623a4b9c9).

---

[Supervisord is already installed](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.0/Dockerfile#L15)

Answer (score 2):

Laravel Sail is designed as a development environment and as such I believe Laravel have purposefully omitted automatic running of cron jobs and queue workers in favour of giving developers control over running them using the appropriate artisan commands.

To [use the Laravel Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler-locally) inside Sail you can simply run:

```
sail artisan schedule:work
```

This command will run in the foreground and invoke the scheduler every minute until you terminate the command.

Similarly, if you want to [run the Queue worker](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#the-queue-work-command) inside Sail you can run the following:

```
sail artisan queue:work
```

Running these commands locally gives the developer complete control rather than having tasks and queues running automatically inside the container.

**I would strongly recommend sticking with running these commands manually so that your app doesn't unexpectedly fire out a million emails that are sat in the queue or run other unintended jobs or tasks!**

If, against this advice, you did want to have the Laravel scheduler run automatically inside the Sail docker container then the steps would be something like this:

1. Publish the Sail docker assets using `sail artisan sail:publish`
2. Edit the Dockerfile to add the cron package e.g. `RUN apt-get install -y cron`
3. Edit the Dockerfile to create an [appropriate cron job](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler) in `/etc/cron.d/laravel`
4. Edit the Dockerfile to start the cron service e.g. `RUN /usr/sbin/service cron start`
5. Rebuild the Sail docker container with `sail build --no-cache`

Similarly, after publishing the Sail assets you could also edit the provided `supervisord.conf` to [automatically run queues](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#configuring-supervisor) using supervisord.

Comment: I agree that adding a scheduler to sail doesn't seem right.

Comment: @ultrasamad not really if you are trying to test environments that is the purpose of docker to run the same setup as your production environments. If you don't have that running then you will never know that things arent working properly, which is critical to understanding on a local environment. Example, a feature that uploads csv of thousands of records, you will have jobs that do service logic in the background.

Comment: @tmarois that may be one purpose of docker but it certainly is not the purpose of sail which is a tool for interacting with Laravel's default Docker **development environment**.

Answer (score 2):

1. Execute `php artisan sail:publish`, it will publish a docker directory in your project root directory.
2. Add the scheduler/crontab file into the docker runtime folder (i.g: docker/8.2/scheduler)

```
* * * * * root cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run --no-interaction >> /var/www/html/storage/logs/cron.log 2>&1
```

3. Update docker/8.2/Dockerfile

- before `&& apt-get install -y yarn \` add `&& apt-get install -y cron \`
- after `RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ...`, add the following lines:

```
COPY scheduler /etc/cron.d/scheduler
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/scheduler \
    && crontab /etc/cron.d/scheduler
```

4. Update docker/8.2/supervisord.conf file, by adding the following lines:

```
[program:cron]

    command=/usr/sbin/cron -f -l 8
    autostart=true
    stdout_logfile=/var/log/cron.out.log
    stderr_logfile=/var/log/cron.err.log
```

And the following if you want to run horizon too:

```
[program:horizon]

    process_name=%(program_name)s
    command=/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan horizon
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    user=sail
    redirect_stderr=true
    stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/storage/logs/horizon.log
    stopwaitsecs=360
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. Now I understand how to customize the docker images for testing. FWIW, after customizing please be sure to rebuild the image using `sail build --no-cache` see https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#sail-customization. Also, I later found out the using the `php artisan schedule:work` command locally meets my needs for local development: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler-locally)

Comment: There is an issue with your code `crontab /etc/cron.d/scheduler`, it fails with the error that `scheduler` is not an actual file. It is actually a directory. It is supposed to be `crontab /etc/cron.d/scheduler/crontab`, yes?.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem another way. I added this codes to sail's supervisor.conf file.

```
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan horizon
user=sail
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/horizon.log
stopwaitsecs=3600

[program:cron-job]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=crond -f
user=root           ; crond should be started as root at all times
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=false
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Maybe it is not best solution but it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

1. Check your docker-compose.yml file to find laravel.test -> build -> context to ensure sail package. Exp: `./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2`
2. Create a directory beside `app` directory and copy sail runtimes files to it. Exp: `sail`.
3. Edit supervisord.conf file in created directory `sail` and add these lines:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[program:php]
command=/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
user=sail
environment=LARAVEL_SAIL="1"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[include]
files = /var/www/html/supervisor/*.conf
```

You can create `supervisor` directory and put your supervisor config file into it.

You should run `./vendor/bin/sail down` and `./vendor/bin/sail build` to rebuild your configs then you can run `./vendor/bin/sail up -d` to up containers.

Answer (score -1):

To setup [Supervisor for Laravel queues](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#configuring-supervisor), this is what I tried within the Docker container for Laravel Sail.

To enter the container:

```sh
docker-compose exec laravel.test bash
```

Run inside the container:

```sh
apt update
apt install nano
cd /etc/supervisor/conf.d
touch laravel-worker.conf
nano laravel-worker.conf
```

Paste in:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=false
user=root
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/laravel-worker.log
pidfile=/var/run/laravel-worker.pid

[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=sail
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/storage/logs/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
startsecs=0

[supervisorctl]
```

Save with Nano:

```
ctrl + o
ctrl + x
```

To run the queue workers:

```sh
supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf
```

To restart the queue workers if your application code changes:

```sh
service supervisor restart
```

> Remember, queue workers, are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory. As a result, they will not notice changes in your code base after they have been started. So, during your deployment process, be sure to restart your queue workers. In addition, remember that any static state created or modified by your application will not be automatically reset between jobs. [Queues - Laravel - Running the Queue Worker](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

*Note: if the Docker container is restarted, you'll need to manually run the supervisord command again.*

From digging into Laravel Sail a bit, it looks like you shouldn't change `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf` since it's so tied into Docker. For example, if the supervisor process is killed, the container stops i.e. the webserver stops and you're logged out. This makes it more difficult to change the queue worker configuration since it requires restarting the process.

See [sail/runtimes/8.0/start-container](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.0/start-container).

Final thoughts: Overall, if I had to start over again knowing what I know now, I might have configured Supervisor (and cron) outside of the Docker container on the host system. It's less complicated and probably less prone to breaking in the future in case of Sail updates.

Comment: I tried similar method but it's not permanent.